# Selenium 2: something wrong with code “driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("");”

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I use the code

```
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("name");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("12345");
```

to login to a website. Sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't, the error given is

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"name","selector":"username"}

The problem is that sometimes it will work. Should I perhaps use `Byxpath（）`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WebDriverWait with conditions to wait for Elements:

```
public class MyTestClass{

    private static final int MAX_WAIT_TIME_SEC = 60;
    private WebDriverWait wait;
    [...]

    public void setField(String fieldname, String text){
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, MAX_WAIT_TIME_SEC);
        wait.until(new NameExpectedCondition(xpath));
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(fieldname));
        if(element != null){
            element.sendKeys(text);
        }
        [...]
    }

    public void foo()
}
```

With NameExpectedCondition:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class NameExpectedCondition implements ExpectedCondition<Boolean> {

private String fieldName;

public NameExpectedCondition(String fieldName)
{
    this.fieldName= fieldName;
}

public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
    d.findElement(By.Name(fieldName));
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

}

Please make also sure you're searching for the element in the correct frame.

Answer (score 2):

You might not be waiting till the element loads in the page. Its a good practice to use `selenium.isElementPresent(locator)` or `selenium.isVisible(locator)` before the `sendKeys` or similar commands command execution.

Comment: What AJ77 said. Webdriver is going through web pages very fast, it's often necessary to use isXPresent(x) or isVisible(x) to ensure the page will be properly loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is the most simple way to solve this problem:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
```

It will handle all NoSuchElementExceptions just trying to refind an element.

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));

Answer (score 1):

Please add this command before you send `FindElement`:

```
String strTemp = driver.PageSource;
```

You'll see the source doesn't load the whole page.